# I need to extact text from H1 SPAN no class with Beautifulsoup and remove brackets

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

H1 is unique

```
<h1>Anno <span>(2021)</span></h1>
```

I need to extact text from H1 SPAN no class with Beautifulsoup and remove brackets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the working solution:

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

```
tag="""
<h1>    
 Anno   
 <span> 
  (2021)
 </span>
</h1>

"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(tag, 'html.parser')
span= soup.select_one('h1 span').text.replace('(', '').replace(')', '')
print(span)
```

Output

```
2021
```

Comment: don't need to add .text() at last?